# Fortran Encode 'R' Formatter

Tags: format, fortran, encode

I am translating some FORTRAN code to java, but there is a formatter type that I can't really understand, and I didn't find its meaning on the internet.

I have line like this `ENCODE(2,'(R2)',BUFFER) MY_DATA` but I don't know what the '(R2)' formatter means.

Someone knows ?

Comment: To my knowledge there's never been an R edit descriptor in Fortran. My first guess would be for a real, but just the single number afterwards doesn't really tally with that. Can you can give us any hint as to the machine one which the code was first developed? Anything in the comments, perhaps?

Comment: This is non-standard Fortran, the oracle documentation mentions it as radix control, but has the number in front of the r, such that 2R would mean binary representation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/z40007437a2e/index.html Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I don't know what compiler have been used, all I know is that the code is from 1999...Also, the code is used to write hexa values to a file. I think maybe this notation 'R2' could means to write the value as a two digits hexa decimal value, but since I don't get the same result in my program, I am trying to know what it really does, and if the error is coming from here or somewhere else in my code

Comment: Could you gives us a bit more context then? Ideally with what the inputs and expected outputs of the encode statement are? Unfortunately this stuff was never standard Fortran, so it could be quite difficult to work out what is intended.